# Connecting to firebase admin sdk using service account key

Tags: firebase-admin, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am using Cloud Run Continuous Deployment to watch a github repo & build the project upon a push to the production branch. Instead of specifying a Dockerfile, I am letting Google Cloud Buildpacks do all the work, since my codebase is written in Node.js.

I haven't yet been able to run a functional deployment due to the service account running into some permissions errors, but once I get past those, I am wondering how I would be able to initialize the firebase admin SDK inside the build. In my dev code, I have a service account JSON file and initialize the admin SDK using that file, but I don't know if this possible in the cloud build. If I can't upload private files to the cloud build, am I able to use the service account that creates the build to initialize the admin sdk? Is there another way to initialize the admin app in the build, such as using env variables? For reference, I am only using the admin sdk to read and write to our firestore database.

Comment: Look into application default credentials, so that you don't have to worry about service accounts at all. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

Comment: So you are not handling a yaml or json build config file for the Cloud Build right? You are using Cloud Native Buildpacks. Is that correct?